# POSTGRES DB Server Blunder

Tags: postgresql, recovery

This weekend I had to rebuild my laptop which had Postgres running. For some reason, I forgot to dump the data but I did make a complete copy of the original hard drive.

Is it possible to recover data from the original data files to transfer to another instance of Postgres?

Comment: Old and new PostgreSQL versions and host operating systems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly simple. You need to copy the database from the old disk image to a directory in the new host then start it using the *same* major version of PostgreSQL compiled with the same options (integer datetimes on/off, etc).

You can start the DB with a command like `PGPORT=5433 pg_ctl -D /path/to/copy/of/old/database start`. You *must* use the same PostgreSQL major version that the DB was created with before. If you're not sure what that was, check the `PG_VERSION` file in old data directory.

Once you've started a server with the old database you can then `pg_dump` the databases(s) and `pg_dumpall --globals-only` the users, etc, and load them into the new database.

**Do not try to start the database directly on the old disk image, make a copy and start the copy**.

You haven't provided details about versions, operating systems, how you installed Pg on the old and new machines, etc, so it's hard to provide more detail.

Comment: Craig,

Thank you for your help. I will work on this later today. 

Thank you again.

Ray